# How do I declare a Telephone field in a content entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I want to create a custom content entity with a telephone field. I'm baffled on how to do it; I can't figure out what should go into `setDisplayOptions()` to have it show up as a telephone field on the form. Does anyone know where I could find an example of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, the following configuration seemed to work:

```
$fields['display_number'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('telephone')
      ->setLabel(t('Display Number'))
      ->setDescription((t('The phone number to display')))
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'telephone_default',
        'weight' => 0,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```